# Replacing MDX Parameters in Query String

Tags: c#, .net, mdx, olap-cube, query-string

I'm new to MDX queries and am having trouble figuring out how to use the adomd parameters correctly .The query string I'm working with is given below:

```
Select {
    [Measures].[Unit On Order], 
    [Measures].[Cost On Order], 
    [Measures].[Retail On Order] 
} on columns, 
NON EMPTY 
{ 
    [Product].[Universal Customer Choice Code].&amp;[@GlobalId] 
} 
* 
{ 
    [Date].[01 - Fiscal Week].[@StartFiscalWeek] : [Date].[01 - Fiscal Week].[@EndFiscalWeek] 
} on rows 
from [Buy Plan] 
where ( 
    [Brand].[Brand].[@Brand], 
    [Market].[Market].[@Market], 
    [Reporting Currency].[Reporting Currency].&amp;[@ReportingCurrency]
    )
```

I have been adding parameters as such:

```
 var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
 parameter.ParameterName = argument.Key;
 parameter.Value = argument.Value;
 command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

When I manually replace the @parameters, the result has values. However, I am unable to do the same using the Adomd Parameters. I've seen some people suggesting StrToSet() and StrToMember(). I'm familiar with neither, nor have I been able to figure out the difference between Set and Member.

I think all that I need is to know how to correctly format my QueryString. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy moly i figured it out! Probably a simple answer for those of you who know how to use MDX but maybe this'll be useful for someone else.

My first problem: My parameters were formatted incorrectly.

```
 var param_wrong = new AdomdParameter("@Global", 012345);
```

That's incorrect because the '@' should not be included in the parameter declaration, only within the Query string.

```
 var param_almost_correct = new AdomdParameter("Global", 012345);
```

My second problem: My initial query string didn't include StrToMember. I finally figured out how to use it. StrToMember should include the entire field. Now the parameter should reflect this.

```
 var param_correct = new AdomdParameter("Global", [Product].[Universal Customer Choice Code].[000113416000]);
```

The third problem and final change was creating a properly formatted query string, given below.

```
   Select { 
   [Measures].[Unit On Order], 
   [Measures].[Cost On Order], 
   [Measures].[Retail On Order] } 
   on columns, 
   NON EMPTY {  
      StrToMember(@GlobalId) } * 
     { StrToMember(@StartFiscalWeek) : StrToMember(@EndFiscalWeek) } 
   on rows from [Buy Plan] 
   where( 
      StrToMember(@Brand), 
      StrToMember(@Market), 
      StrToMember(@ReportingCurrency) )
```

However, I do have some remaining questions. Why does the parameter and StrToMember require that the whole field be used? Why can't I just have the query string look like:

```
 [Product].[Universal Customer Choice Code].[StrToMember(@GlobalId)]
```

I tried it like this but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Since the comment was long, adding it as an answer.

> However, I do have some remaining questions. Why does the parameter
>   and StrToMember require that the whole field be used? Why can't I just
>   have the query string look like:

```
[Product].[Universal Customer Choice Code].[StrToMember(@GlobalId)]
```

Hard to explain why, that's just the syntax! You can't use `StrToMember` inside a statement like that.

An alternate way to build the query would have been:

```
StrToMember("[Product].[Universal Customer Choice Code].[" + @GlobalId + "]")
```

See what happened here?

What `@GlobalID` passes from your report is a string value. You can concat this value to static strings and convert this to a well-formed member definition. Next step would be to just convert this string to a `member` by using the `StrToMember` function.

Do note that if you intend to add more members in future, then `StrToMember` function wont work anymore. You would have to use `StrToSet`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this was also helpful.